# Jquery mobile navigation issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, navigation

I use simpledialog in jquery mobile app. It works fine when running in normal browser width.
But when I reduce screen width less than 250px (apprx.)(Screen width matching mobile) the URL starts appending #&ui-state=dialog with the current URL. And the issue is with the redirection also. One of my button links to other page. And when I clicked on that button it redirects to specified page and return back to current page. But if I do the same once again there wont be any issue. Can anyone help me solve this?

My code for simple dialog is as follows :

```
$('#create_invoice').append('<div id="temp_div_popup" style="width:80px;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;"></div>');
$('#temp_div_popup').simpledialog({
    'buttons':{
        'Edit':{
            click:function () {
                operation = 'edit_exist';
                if (type == 'item') {
                    $.mobile.changePage('add_item.html',{
                        transition : 'none',
                        allowSamePageTransition : true
                    });
                }
                else if (type == 'task') {
                    $.mobile.changePage('add_task.html',{
                        transition : 'none',
                        allowSamePageTransition : true
                    });
                }
                $('#temp_div_popup').remove();
            }
        },
        'Delete':{
            click:function () {
                deleteItemOrTask(type);
                $('#temp_div_popup').remove();
            }
        },

        'Cancel':{
            click:function () {
                $('#temp_div_popup').remove();
            },
            icon:"delete",
            theme:"c"
        }
    },
    'height' :function(){
        return '55px;'
    },
    'width' : function(){
        return '140px';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is generally seen in smaller views only like in mobile phones. It can be simulated by resizing the browser to smaller window. I solved the issue by removing this plugin and adding my own custom dialog window. :)